Static solution to an implicitly dynamic problem - heat equation
Heat equation
This is the heat equation:
$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
   = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}
$
Now let's assume $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$
Then the equation would become:
$
-\Delta u = 1
$
Solving PDE
The equation $-\Delta u = 1$ is solved here. It can be solved for a variety of input 2D or 3D meshes.
For example, consider input to be a 2D square disc with a hole in it:


Question: how to justify the result
Static solution to an implicitly dynamic problem
Now, I cannot justify the final results. What do the results mean?
The assumption of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$ on heat equation would mean that the temperature is going down with a linear slope/rate of -1 then we are getting a static final heat distribution. The final distribution does not vary with time. It's static. What does it mean? Why the temperature is not reducing with a linear slope pf -1? I know the FEM tool we used doesn't consider the time variation. But what's the physical meaning of getting a static solution to a problem that is implicitly dynamic?
I know this might be a stupid question to ask. But I guess I'm missing something here.

Why have you assumed $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$?

@Gonçalo Well, I didn't assume that. But I looked at the $-\Delta u = 1$ equation and I thought it was just the heat equation with the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1$ assumption. Then I wondered what is the physical meaning of the solution results...

you have assumed $u=f(x)+g(t)$

@user619894 That's right. Looks like by considering the heat equation as $\Delta u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -1$ then I'm actually assuming that $u=f(x,y) - t$ so the final solution results are displaying the $f(x,y)$ part of the $u$ ...

For the 3D space, generically, I have:
$
u=f(x,y,z,t)
$
As pointed out by @user619894 when I set:
$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-1
$
$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
   = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
      + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} = -1
$
Actually, I'm making an assumption here:
$
u=f(x,y,z) - t
$
So, for the 2D example, the resulted graphs are displaying the $f(x,y)$ part of the $u$:
$
u=f(x,y) - t
$
Therefore, the displayed graphs are initial temperatures at $t=0$
Am I right? Looks like I got the answer to my question.
